# elastic search array score

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch

I have a document has an array like

doc1

```
{
"item_type":"bag",
"color":["red","blue","green","orange"]
}
```

doc2

```
{
"item_type":"shirt",
"color":["red"]
}
```

when I do a multi_match search like

`{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "red bag",
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "fields": ["item_type","color"]
        }
    }
}`

The doc2 has much higher score, I understand color filed has less items get higher score and it get worse if I have more colors in doc1.

So is there a way I can ask Elasticsearch to score the same for an array field no matter how many items are there?

Comment: Do you want to use a `multi_match` no matter what?

Comment: Do you get better results if you add `"use_dis_max": false` to your `multi_match`?

Comment: use_dis_max:false does not help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to account for field length (fieldNorm) during the scoring you could disable [norms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#norms) for a field in the mapping.

For example the mapping for the above example would be

```
   {
   "properties": {
      "item_type": {
         "type": "string"
      },
      "color": {
         "type": "string",
         "norms": {
            "enabled": false
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This [article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#field-norm) from elasticsearch definitive guide gives a good insight into field-length-norms.